# How to hide the webgrid when execute the page in mvc3 razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

When I remove the webgrid and layout=null in the view, its executing and client side validation message is displaying... but When I execute the page with layout= nlll and Webgrid it displaying the below error "A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed"

Controller :

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public ActionResult Display()
        {
              return View();
        }

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Display(string brandname)
        {

            ShoppingClass s = new ShoppingClass();

           var ob= s.Searching(brandname);

            return View(ob);

        }
```

view :

```
@model List<ShoppingCart.Models.ShoppingClass>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Display";
      Layout = null;
}

 @{
     var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort: "Drug_Code", rowsPerPage: 20);
}


<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>




        @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
      @*
            <table><tr><td> @Html.Label("BrandName")</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("BrandName")<div>@Html.ValidationMessage("BrandName")</div></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Search" name="Search" /></td></tr></table>*@


            <table><tr><td> @Html.LabelFor(o => o[i].BrandName)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o[i].BrandName)<div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o[i].BrandName)</div></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Search" name="Search" /></td></tr></table>


            }

        }

    <div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "listing-border", headerStyle: "gridhead", footerStyle: "paging", rowStyle: "td-dark", alternatingRowStyle: "td-light",
       columns: grid.Columns(
                   grid.Column("GenericName", format: @<text>@item.GenericName</text>),
                   grid.Column("BrandName", format: @<text>@item.BrandName</text>),
                   grid.Column("Purchaseqty", format: @<text>@item.Purchaseqty</text>),
                   grid.Column("Purchaseprice", format: @<text>@item.Purchaseprice</text>),
                   grid.Column("Drug_Code", format: @<text>@item.Drug_Code</text>),
                   grid.Column(header: "", format: (item) => Ajax.ActionLink("Add to Cart", "ADDTOCART",
                   new { brandname = @item.BrandName, purchaseqty = @item.Purchaseqty, drugcode = @item.Drug_Code }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "ADDTOCART" }))

                                                                                                )
                                                                                                )
</div>
```

Comment: what does `s.Searching()` return ? a `List`, ??

Comment: Searching is the function written in class and passing the value to that function as a list

Comment: your function will be returning a `List<ShoppingClass>` is this rite ?

Comment: ohhh, if after your first action `Display()` you are getting this error, it is obivious as Model is null at that time and you are passing a null value to a webgrid source.

Comment: Yeah model passing null values to grid. How to overcome this problem

Comment: well, supply a filled model from the action

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the grid if the model is null, then you can put an if statement in that checks if the model is null... ie.

```
if (model != null)
{
    // Make and populate grid here
}
```